# Prove equality between summations and products

Tags: proof-verification, summation, proof-writing, education

How can I prove the equality between the following summations and products?

$$\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{M}{b_m z^{-m}}} {\sum_{n=0}^{N}{a_n z^{-n}}}= \frac{b_0}{a_0} \frac{\prod_{m=0}^{M}{1-c_m z^{-1}}}{\prod_{n=0}^{N}{1-d_n z^{-1}}}$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In general, you can't  -because without further assumptions on the $a_i,b_i,c_id_i$ it is just wrong

Comment: Hi @HagenvonEitzen. Could you help me to formulate assumptions that link the coefficients please?

Comment: It has to do with the factorization of polynomials.

Comment: Yeah, this seems there is something wrong or missing here... If you try to expand both sides for a small $N$, as $2$, for example, you can see that the order of the polynomials don't match!